# Druid Ingestion Failed

Tags: hadoop, druid

I am following the steps on the druid website: http://druid.io/docs/latest/tutorials/quickstart.html

But for some reason it keeps giving me this error:

```
2016-07-19T22:44:36,276 ERROR [task-runner-0-priority-0] io.druid.indexing.overlord.ThreadPoolTaskRunner - Exception while running task[HadoopIndexTask{id=index_hadoop_wikiticker_2016-07-19T22:44:25.500Z, type=index_hadoop, dataSource=wikiticker}]
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at com.google.common.base.Throwables.propagate(Throwables.java:160) ~[guava-16.0.1.jar:?]
    at io.druid.indexing.common.task.HadoopTask.invokeForeignLoader(HadoopTask.java:204) ~[druid-indexing-service-0.9.1.1.jar:0.9.1.1]
    at io.druid.indexing.common.task.HadoopIndexTask.run(HadoopIndexTask.java:208) ~[druid-indexing-service-0.9.1.1.jar:0.9.1.1]
    at io.druid.indexing.overlord.ThreadPoolTaskRunner$ThreadPoolTaskRunnerCallable.call(ThreadPoolTaskRunner.java:436) [druid-indexing-service-0.9.1.1.jar:0.9.1.1]
    at io.druid.indexing.overlord.ThreadPoolTaskRunner$ThreadPoolTaskRunnerCallable.call(ThreadPoolTaskRunner.java:408) [druid-indexing-service-0.9.1.1.jar:0.9.1.1]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262) [?:1.7.0_79]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145) [?:1.7.0_79]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615) [?:1.7.0_79]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [?:1.7.0_79]
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[?:1.7.0_79]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57) ~[?:1.7.0_79]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[?:1.7.0_79]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606) ~[?:1.7.0_79]
    at io.druid.indexing.common.task.HadoopTask.invokeForeignLoader(HadoopTask.java:201) ~[druid-indexing-service-0.9.1.1.jar:0.9.1.1]
    ... 7 more
Caused by: com.metamx.common.ISE: Job[class io.druid.indexer.IndexGeneratorJob] failed!
    at io.druid.indexer.JobHelper.runJobs(JobHelper.java:343) ~[druid-indexing-hadoop-0.9.1.1.jar:0.9.1.1]
    at io.druid.indexer.HadoopDruidIndexerJob.run(HadoopDruidIndexerJob.java:94) ~[druid-indexing-hadoop-0.9.1.1.jar:0.9.1.1]
    at io.druid.indexing.common.task.HadoopIndexTask$HadoopIndexGeneratorInnerProcessing.runTask(HadoopIndexTask.java:261) ~[druid-indexing-service-0.9.1.1.jar:0.9.1.1]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[?:1.7.0_79]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57) ~[?:1.7.0_79]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[?:1.7.0_79]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606) ~[?:1.7.0_79]
    at io.druid.indexing.common.task.HadoopTask.invokeForeignLoader(HadoopTask.java:201) ~[druid-indexing-service-0.9.1.1.jar:0.9.1.1]
    ... 7 more
```

Does anyone know the reason for this? Even when I go to the console: http://localhost:8090/console.html It says that my ingestion failed.

Comment: Do you still have the whole log if that ingestion task? It can be accessed from the same console you mentioned. The full log usually contains some previous exceptions/errors that resulted in task's failure

Comment: @LP45 hey...have you got answer? I am also facing same problem with druid. It fails all task which i create.

Comment: I would assume an issue with the Hadoop setup. Have you copied the Hadoop config files (core-site.xml etc.) to Druid's config directory?

Comment: Check middleManager log.  The log tells you the path of Peon log.  Check the Peon log.   A lot of things can go wrong, but the common problem is jar version discrepancy between Hadoop and Druid.  See [this document](https://github.com/jon-wei/druid/blob/2352cd68f74f73d3b9f68dc4c8274977cfeca4ea/docs/content/operations/other-hadoop.md#overriding-specific-classes).  This document talks about multiple solutions but you should try the "Overriding specific classes."  None of other methods worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Check if the console is running and the coordinator has no issues with the worker threads